# ui-router is not showing my view

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app ng-csp>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Presently</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app/styles/angular-csp.css">
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">-->

    <script src="assets/dependencies/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/dependencies/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>

    <script src="main.js"></script>

    <script src="app/states/home/home.controller.js"></script>
    <script src="app/states/home/favs/fav.controller.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    hello {{'foo'.length}}

    <div ui-view></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

main.js:

```
console.log('main.js');

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router'])
.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouteProvider'
  , function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

  $stateProvider
    .state('state1', {
      url: "/",
      template: "home"
    });
}]);

console.log(myApp);
```

So the console logs show for `main.js` and the app but nothing is rendered in the view. I would expect to see the word 'home'

Comment: Never used template as a string like this, only templateUrl = "/path/to/template.html ... is it working if you switch to it? (aka at least making a get request to templateUrl? )

Comment: Which version of angular u r using ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had a typo *(`$urlRouteProvider` instead of the `$urlRouterProvider`)*

```
.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouteProvider'
, function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
```

Which I fixed here in [this working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/5pAiuITVZGb8tqrfzr92?p=preview)

```
.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider'
, function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
```

Check the **`Router`** in the  `$urlRouterProvider`

Comment: Well, great that we made it. Enjoy awesome UI-Router sir ;)